# AWS Managed elastic Search restore - node does not match index setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Im trying to restore the ElasticSearch snapshot which is taken from the AWS managed elastic search. Version 5.6. Instance type `i3.2xlarge`.

While restoring this on a VM, immediately the cluster status went to Red and all the shards are unassigned.

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "es-cluster",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 8,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 5,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 480,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 0.0
}
```

When I use the allocation explain API, I got this below response.

```
 {
      "node_id" : "3WEV1tHoRPm6OguKyxp0zg",
      "node_name" : "node-1",
      "transport_address" : "10.0.0.2:9300",
      "node_decision" : "no",
      "deciders" : [
        {
          "decider" : "replica_after_primary_active",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "primary shard for this replica is not yet active"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "filter",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "node does not match index setting [index.routing.allocation.include] filters [instance_type:\"i2.2xlarge OR i3.2xlarge\"]"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "throttling",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "primary shard for this replica is not yet active"
        }
      ]
    },
```

This is something strange and I never faced this. Anyhow the snapshot is done, How can I ignore this setting while restoring? Even I tried the below query but still the same issue.

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_snapshot/restore/awsnap/_restore?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"ignore_index_settings": [
    "index.routing.allocation.include"
  ]
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the cause and the solution.

Detailed troubleshooting steps are here https://thedataguy.in/restore-aws-elasticsearch-snapshot-failed-index-settings/

But leaving this comment here, so others can get benefit from it.

This is AWS specific thing, So I used this to solve it.

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_snapshot/restore/awsnap/_restore?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"ignore_index_settings": [
    "index.routing.allocation.include.instance_type"
  ]
}
'
```